# How to implement a 24 hour trading calendar with Zipline. Can't instantiate abstract class {} with abstract methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, zipline

I am following an online tutorial to set up zipline with a 24 hour calender and perform a backtest. I am running python 2.7. I am using spyder. I have a mac using OSX 10.11.6.

I have exactly the same problem as stated in this post however I do not understand the how the problem was solved.

[TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class { } with abstract methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386772/typeerror-cant-instantiate-abstract-class-with-abstract-methods)

When I attempt to execute the code I get the message can't instantiate abstract class {} with abstract methods.

Can someone please give me some help and advice on what steps I should take to resolve the issue?

Its probably not very useful but I have attached some of the TradingCalendar code for you to see.

Thank you for any help.

```
#
# Copyright 2018 Quantopian, Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty
from lru import LRU
import warnings

from operator import attrgetter
from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar
from six import with_metaclass
import numpy as np
from numpy import searchsorted
import pandas as pd
from pandas import (
    DataFrame,
    date_range,
    DatetimeIndex,
)
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
import toolz

from .calendar_helpers import (
    compute_all_minutes,
    is_open,
    next_divider_idx,
    previous_divider_idx,
)
from .utils.memoize import lazyval
from .utils.pandas_utils import days_at_time
from .utils.preprocess import preprocess, coerce


start_default = pd.Timestamp('1990-01-01', tz='UTC')
end_base = pd.Timestamp('today', tz='UTC')
# Give an aggressive buffer for logic that needs to use the next trading
# day or minute.
end_default = end_base + pd.Timedelta(days=365)

NANOS_IN_MINUTE = 60000000000
MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY = range(7)
WEEKDAYS = (MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY)
WEEKENDS = (SATURDAY, SUNDAY)


def selection(arr, start, end):
    predicates = []
    if start is not None:
        predicates.append(start.tz_localize('UTC') <= arr)
    if end is not None:
        predicates.append(arr < end.tz_localize('UTC'))

    if not predicates:
        return arr

    return arr[np.all(predicates, axis=0)]


def _group_times(all_days, times, tz, offset):
    elements = [
        days_at_time(
            selection(all_days, start, end),
            time,
            tz,
            offset
        )
        for (start, time), (end, _) in toolz.sliding_window(
            2,
            toolz.concatv(times, [(None, None)])
        )
    ]
    return elements[0].append(elements[1:])


class TradingCalendar(with_metaclass(ABCMeta)):
    """
    An TradingCalendar represents the timing information of a single market
    exchange.

    The timing information is made up of two parts: sessions, and opens/closes.

    A session represents a contiguous set of minutes, and has a label that is
    midnight UTC. It is important to note that a session label should not be
    considered a specific point in time, and that midnight UTC is just being
    used for convenience.

    For each session, we store the open and close time in UTC time.
    """
    def __init__(self, start=start_default, end=end_default):
        # Midnight in UTC for each trading day.

        # In pandas 0.18.1, pandas calls into its own code here in a way that
        # fires a warning. The calling code in pandas tries to suppress the
        # warning, but does so incorrectly, causing it to bubble out here.
        # Actually catch and suppress the warning here:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
            _all_days = date_range(start, end, freq=self.day, tz='UTC')

        # `DatetimeIndex`s of standard opens/closes for each day.
        self._opens = _group_times(
            _all_days,
            self.open_times,
            self.tz,
            self.open_offset,
        )
        self._closes = _group_times(
            _all_days,
            self.close_times,
            self.tz,
            self.close_offset,
        )

        # `Series`s mapping sessions with nonstandard opens/closes to
        # the open/close time.
        _special_opens = self._calculate_special_opens(start, end)
        _special_closes = self._calculate_special_closes(start, end)

        # Overwrite the special opens and closes on top of the standard ones.
        _overwrite_special_dates(_all_days, self._opens, _special_opens)
        _overwrite_special_dates(_all_days, self._closes, _special_closes)

        # In pandas 0.16.1 _opens and _closes will lose their timezone
        # information. This looks like it has been resolved in 0.17.1.
        # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#datetime-with-tz  # noqa
        self.schedule = DataFrame(
            index=_all_days,
            columns=['market_open', 'market_close'],
            data={
                'market_open': self._opens,
                'market_close': self._closes,
            },
            dtype='datetime64[ns]',
        )

        # Simple cache to avoid recalculating the same minute -> session in
        # "next" mode. Analysis of current zipline code paths show that
        # `minute_to_session_label` is often called consecutively with the same
        # inputs.
        self._minute_to_session_label_cache = LRU(1)

        self.market_opens_nanos = self.schedule.market_open.values.\
            astype(np.int64)

        self.market_closes_nanos = self.schedule.market_close.values.\
            astype(np.int64)

        self._trading_minutes_nanos = self.all_minutes.values.\
            astype(np.int64)

        self.first_trading_session = _all_days[0]
        self.last_trading_session = _all_days[-1]

        self._late_opens = pd.DatetimeIndex(
            _special_opens.map(self.minute_to_session_label)
        )

        self._early_closes = pd.DatetimeIndex(
            _special_closes.map(self.minute_to_session_label)
        )

    @lazyval
    def day(self):
        return CustomBusinessDay(
            holidays=self.adhoc_holidays,
            calendar=self.regular_holidays,
            weekmask=self.weekmask,
        )

    @abstractproperty
    def name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractproperty
    def tz(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractproperty
    def open_times(self):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples of (start_date, open_time).  If the open
        time is constant throughout the calendar, use None for the start_date.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractproperty
    def close_times(self):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples of (start_date, close_time).  If the close
        time is constant throughout the calendar, use None for the start_date.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @property
    def weekmask(self):
        """
        String indicating the days of the week on which the market is open.

        Default is '1111100' (i.e., Monday-Friday).

        See Also
        --------
        numpy.busdaycalendar
        """
        return '1111100'

    @property
    def open_offset(self):
        return 0

    @property
    def close_offset(self):
        return 0

    @lazyval
    def _minutes_per_session(self):
        diff = self.schedule.market_close - self.schedule.market_open
        diff = diff.astype('timedelta64[m]')
        return diff + 1

    def minutes_count_for_sessions_in_range(self, start_session, end_session):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        start_session: pd.Timestamp
            The first session.

        end_session: pd.Timestamp
            The last session.

        Returns
        -------
        int: The total number of minutes for the contiguous chunk of sessions.
             between start_session and end_session, inclusive.
        """
        return int(self._minutes_per_session[start_session:end_session].sum())

    @property
    def regular_holidays(self):
        """
        Returns
        -------
        pd.AbstractHolidayCalendar: a calendar containing the regular holidays
        for this calendar
        """
        return None

    @property
    def adhoc_holidays(self):
        return []

    @property
    def special_opens(self):
        """
        A list of special open times and corresponding HolidayCalendars.

        Returns
        -------
        list: List of (time, AbstractHolidayCalendar) tuples
        """
        return []

    @property
    def special_opens_adhoc(self):
        """
        Returns
        -------
        list: List of (time, DatetimeIndex) tuples that represent special
         closes that cannot be codified into rules.
        """
        return []

    @property
    def special_closes(self):
        """
        A list of special close times and corresponding HolidayCalendars.

        Returns
        -------
        list: List of (time, AbstractHolidayCalendar) tuples
        """
        return []

    @property
    def special_closes_adhoc(self):
        """
        Returns
        -------
        list: List of (time, DatetimeIndex) tuples that represent special
         closes that cannot be codified into rules.
        """
        return []

    # -----

    @property
    def opens(self):
        return self.schedule.market_open

    @property
    def closes(self):
        return self.schedule.market_close

    @property
    def late_opens(self):
        return self._late_opens

    @property
    def early_closes(self):
        return self._early_closes

    def is_session(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, returns whether it's a valid session label.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt that is being tested.

        Returns
        -------
        bool
            Whether the given dt is a valid session label.
        """
        return dt in self.schedule.index

    def is_open_on_minute(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, return whether this exchange is open at the given dt.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to check if this exchange is open.

        Returns
        -------
        bool
            Whether the exchange is open on this dt.
        """
        return is_open(self.market_opens_nanos, self.market_closes_nanos,
                       dt.value)

    def next_open(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, returns the next open.

        If the given dt happens to be a session open, the next session's open
        will be returned.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to get the next open.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The UTC timestamp of the next open.
        """
        idx = next_divider_idx(self.market_opens_nanos, dt.value)
        return pd.Timestamp(self.market_opens_nanos[idx], tz='UTC')

    def next_close(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, returns the next close.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to get the next close.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The UTC timestamp of the next close.
        """
        idx = next_divider_idx(self.market_closes_nanos, dt.value)
        return pd.Timestamp(self.market_closes_nanos[idx], tz='UTC')

    def previous_open(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, returns the previous open.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to get the previous open.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The UTC imestamp of the previous open.
        """
        idx = previous_divider_idx(self.market_opens_nanos, dt.value)
        return pd.Timestamp(self.market_opens_nanos[idx], tz='UTC')

    def previous_close(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, returns the previous close.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to get the previous close.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The UTC timestamp of the previous close.
        """
        idx = previous_divider_idx(self.market_closes_nanos, dt.value)
        return pd.Timestamp(self.market_closes_nanos[idx], tz='UTC')

    def next_minute(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, return the next exchange minute.  If the given dt is not
        an exchange minute, returns the next exchange open.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to get the next exchange minute.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The next exchange minute.
        """
        idx = next_divider_idx(self._trading_minutes_nanos, dt.value)
        return self.all_minutes[idx]

    def previous_minute(self, dt):
        """
        Given a dt, return the previous exchange minute.

        Raises KeyError if the given timestamp is not an exchange minute.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dt: pd.Timestamp
            The dt for which to get the previous exchange minute.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The previous exchange minute.
        """

        idx = previous_divider_idx(self._trading_minutes_nanos, dt.value)
        return self.all_minutes[idx]

    def next_session_label(self, session_label):
        """
        Given a session label, returns the label of the next session.

        Parameters
        ----------
        session_label: pd.Timestamp
            A session whose next session is desired.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The next session label (midnight UTC).

        Notes
        -----
        Raises ValueError if the given session is the last session in this
        calendar.
        """
        idx = self.schedule.index.get_loc(session_label)
        try:
            return self.schedule.index[idx + 1]
        except IndexError:
            if idx == len(self.schedule.index) - 1:
                raise ValueError("There is no next session as this is the end"
                                 " of the exchange calendar.")
            else:
                raise

    def previous_session_label(self, session_label):
        """
        Given a session label, returns the label of the previous session.

        Parameters
        ----------
        session_label: pd.Timestamp
            A session whose previous session is desired.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.Timestamp
            The previous session label (midnight UTC).

        Notes
        -----
        Raises ValueError if the given session is the first session in this
        calendar.
        """
        idx = self.schedule.index.get_loc(session_label)
        if idx == 0:
            raise ValueError("There is no previous session as this is the"
                             " beginning of the exchange calendar.")

        return self.schedule.index[idx - 1]

    def minutes_for_session(self, session_label):
        """
        Given a session label, return the minutes for that session.

        Parameters
        ----------
        session_label: pd.Timestamp (midnight UTC)
            A session label whose session's minutes are desired.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DateTimeIndex
            All the minutes for the given session.
        """
        return self.minutes_in_range(
            start_minute=self.schedule.at[session_label, 'market_open'],
            end_minute=self.schedule.at[session_label, 'market_close'],
        )

    def execution_minutes_for_session(self, session_label):
        """
        Given a session label, return the execution minutes for that session.

        Parameters
        ----------
        session_label: pd.Timestamp (midnight UTC)
            A session label whose session's minutes are desired.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DateTimeIndex
            All the execution minutes for the given session.
        """
        return self.minutes_in_range(
            start_minute=self.execution_time_from_open(
                self.schedule.at[session_label, 'market_open'],
            ),
            end_minute=self.execution_time_from_close(
                self.schedule.at[session_label, 'market_close'],
            ),
        )

    def execution_minutes_for_sessions_in_range(self, start, stop):
        minutes = self.execution_minutes_for_session
        return pd.DatetimeIndex(
            np.concatenate([
                minutes(session)
                for session in self.sessions_in_range(start, stop)
            ]),
            tz='UTC',
        )

    def minutes_window(self, start_dt, count):
        start_dt_nanos = start_dt.value
        all_minutes_nanos = self._trading_minutes_nanos
        start_idx = all_minutes_nanos.searchsorted(start_dt_nanos)

        # searchsorted finds the index of the minute **on or after** start_dt.
        # If the latter, push back to the prior minute.
        if all_minutes_nanos[start_idx] != start_dt_nanos:
            start_idx -= 1

        if start_idx < 0 or start_idx >= len(all_minutes_nanos):
            raise KeyError("Can't start minute window at {}".format(start_dt))

        end_idx = start_idx + count

        if start_idx > end_idx:
            return self.all_minutes[(end_idx + 1):(start_idx + 1)]
        else:
            return self.all_minutes[start_idx:end_idx]

    def sessions_in_range(self, start_session_label, end_session_label):
        """
        Given start and end session labels, return all the sessions in that
        range, inclusive.

        Parameters
        ----------
        start_session_label: pd.Timestamp (midnight UTC)
            The label representing the first session of the desired range.

        end_session_label: pd.Timestamp (midnight UTC)
            The label representing the last session of the desired range.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DatetimeIndex
            The desired sessions.
        """
        return self.all_sessions[
            self.all_sessions.slice_indexer(
                start_session_label,
                end_session_label
            )
        ]

    def sessions_window(self, session_label, count):
        """
        Given a session label and a window size, returns a list of sessions
        of size `count` + 1, that either starts with the given session
        (if `count` is positive) or ends with the given session (if `count` is
        negative).

        Parameters
        ----------
        session_label: pd.Timestamp
            The label of the initial session.

        count: int
            Defines the length and the direction of the window.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DatetimeIndex
            The desired sessions.
        """
        start_idx = self.schedule.index.get_loc(session_label)
        end_idx = start_idx + count

        return self.all_sessions[
            min(start_idx, end_idx):max(start_idx, end_idx) + 1
        ]

    def session_distance(self, start_session_label, end_session_label):
        """
        Given a start and end session label, returns the distance between them.
        For example, for three consecutive sessions Mon., Tues., and Wed,
        ``session_distance(Mon, Wed)`` returns 3. If ``start_session`` is after
        ``end_session``, the value will be negated.

        Parameters
        ----------
        start_session_label: pd.Timestamp
            The label of the start session.
        end_session_label: pd.Timestamp
            The label of the ending session inclusive.

        Returns
        -------
        int
            The distance between the two sessions.
        """
        negate = end_session_label < start_session_label
        if negate:
            start_session_label, end_session_label = (
                end_session_label,
                start_session_label,
            )
        start_idx = self.all_sessions.searchsorted(start_session_label)
        end_idx = self.all_sessions.searchsorted(
            end_session_label,
            side='right',
        )

        out = end_idx - start_idx
        if negate:
            out = -out

        return out

    def minutes_in_range(self, start_minute, end_minute):
        """
        Given start and end minutes, return all the calendar minutes
        in that range, inclusive.

        Given minutes don't need to be calendar minutes.

        Parameters
        ----------
        start_minute: pd.Timestamp
            The minute representing the start of the desired range.

        end_minute: pd.Timestamp
            The minute representing the end of the desired range.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DatetimeIndex
            The minutes in the desired range.
        """
        start_idx = searchsorted(self._trading_minutes_nanos,
                                 start_minute.value)

        end_idx = searchsorted(self._trading_minutes_nanos,
                               end_minute.value)

        if end_minute.value == self._trading_minutes_nanos[end_idx]:
            # if the end minute is a market minute, increase by 1
            end_idx += 1

        return self.all_minutes[start_idx:end_idx]

    def minutes_for_sessions_in_range(self,
                                      start_session_label,
                                      end_session_label):
        """
        Returns all the minutes for all the sessions from the given start
        session label to the given end session label, inclusive.

        Parameters
        ----------
        start_session_label: pd.Timestamp
            The label of the first session in the range.

        end_session_label: pd.Timestamp
            The label of the last session in the range.

        Returns
        -------
        pd.DatetimeIndex
            The minutes in the desired range.

        """
        first_minute, _ = self.open_and_close_for_session(start_session_label)
        _, last_minute = self.open_and_close_for_session(end_session_label)

        return self.minutes_in_range(first_minute, last_minute)

    def open_and_close_for_session(self, session_label):
        """
        Returns a tuple of timestamps of the open and close of the session
        represented by the given label.

        Parameters
        ----------
        session_label: pd.Timestamp
            The session whose open and close are desired.

        Returns
        -------
        (Timestamp, Timestamp)
            The open and close for the given session.
        """
        sched = self.schedule

        # `market_open` and `market_close` should be timezone aware, but pandas
        # 0.16.1 does not appear to support this:
        # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#datetime-with-tz  # noqa
        return (
            sched.at[session_label, 'market_open'].tz_localize('UTC'),
            sched.at[session_label, 'market_close'].tz_localize('UTC'),
        )

    def session_open(self, session_label):
        return self.schedule.at[
            session_label,
            'market_open'
        ].tz_localize('UTC')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the post [here](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/2412#issuecomment-472390317).

Zipline has replaced the old trading calendar classes with a seperate package `trading_calendars`, but the documents seem to be a bit out of date.

For a 24/7 trading calendar, you can use the `AlwaysOpenCalendar` class provided by the package. It is defined in `trading_calendars/always_open.py`. Or if you need a 24/5 calendar, use `WeekdayCalendar` class in `trading_calendars/weekday_calendar.py`. Just directly instantiate the class will do.